# fstab missing on Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: 12.04, automount, fstab, bind

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 and there is no /etc/fstab
This must be new in 12.04.1 because I was running 12.04 months ago and it was there. I didn't do an upgrade I did a clean install. Where has this file moved to?
I use it to automount my windows partition and to bind folders within that partition to ubuntu

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? (WUBI, installation on a separate partition, ...). And: are you sure? What happens when you do `file /etc/fstab` from command line?

Comment: lsb_release -a :
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
 file /etc/fstab:
/etc/fstab: ASCII text. So, as you can see, it is there in my case.

Comment: How did you know that there is not `/etc/fstab`? You can't even boot to Ubuntu without that file.

Answer (score 2):

> This must be new in 12.04.1 because I was running 12.04 months ago and it was there

No, the file is still `/etc/fstab` in Ubuntu 12.04.1. I installed and used it. Also note, you can't boot to the Ubuntu without that file.

I think, the case is, the new installation of Ubuntu 12.04.1 created a new `/etc/fstab` file and thus your entries to boot Windows drives have been lost.

I suggest you to add those entries again to your `/etc/fstab` file to automount them again.